# Expiring date today in Java

Tags: java, date

I need to check if given date is after today 23:59:59, how can I create date object that is today 23:59:59?

Comment: Do you mean on or after tomorrow at midnight? Or are you interested in  the one second between 23:59:59 and 00:00:00?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [java.util.Calendar](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // represents right now, i.e. today's date
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999); // credit to f1sh

Date date = cal.getTime();
```

I think you might be approaching this from slightly the wrong angle, though.  Instead of trying to create a Date instance that's one atom before midnight, a better approach might be to create the Date that represents midnight and testing whether the current time is *strictly* less than it.  I believe this would be slightly clearer in terms of your intentions to someone else reading the code too.

---

Alternatively, you could use a third-party Date API that knows how to convert back to date.  Java's built-in date API is generally considered to be deficient in many ways.  I wouldn't recommend using another library just to do this, but if you have to do lots of date manipulation and/or are already using a library like [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) you could express this concept more simply.  For example, Joda Time has a `DateMidnight` class that allows much easier comparison against "raw" dates of the type you're doing, without the possibility for subtle problems (like not setting the milliseconds in my first cut).

Comment: Regarding `Calendar.getInstance()`: Keep in mind that the returned `Calendar` also contains the current value for milliseconds. I didn't know that and recently it took me a whole day to find out why `equals()` always returned false.

Comment: Good point f1sh - perhaps the approach here is slightly wrong, see upcoming edit.

Comment: Just include: cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); // or 999

Comment: @Adrian, it's *probably* 999; though that's what I meant by the approach being wrong, and suggesting `< 00:00:00` instead of `<= 23:59:99`.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a date in the future and compares it with the current date (set to late evening). You should consider using the Joda Time Library.

```
long timeStampOfTomorrow = new Date().getTime() + 86400000L;
Date dateToCheck = new Date(timeStampOfTomorrow);


Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);

boolean isExpired = dateToCheck.after(today.getTime());
```

With Joda Time Library you could do this more readable. An easy example can be found on the [project website](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

```
public boolean isRentalOverdue(DateTime datetimeRented) {
    Period rentalPeriod = new Period().withDays(2).withHours(12);
    return datetimeRented.plus(rentalPeriod).isBeforeNow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Use the [Date.before(Date)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) or Date.after(Date)</strike>

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);

Date d = c.getTime()

Date x = // other date from somewhere

x.after(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the tomorrow date convert it into millisecond you get a **long** value.
subtract -1 from it and again convert to date you will get your required date.

ex : 12:00:00 of tomorrow convert it into milliseconds.
     you will get like a long value 312313564774
     subtract -1 you will get today eod time in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant “is the given java.util.Date after today?”.

If so, do not fret about determining the last moment of the day; that is impracticable because of the fractional second. Better to focus on the date only, without the time-of-day. You want to know if the date-only of the given moment is after the date-only of the current moment. A time zone is crucial here.

## tl;dr

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “America/Montreal” );  // Time zone determines date.
Boolean givenMomentIsAfterToday = myUtilDate.toInstant().atZone( z ).toLocalDate().isAfter( LocalDate.now( z ) );
```

## Details

You are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

First, convert the given `java.util.Date` to an `Instant`. Find new conversion methods added to the old classes for converting to/from java.time types.

## `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “America/Montreal” );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Adjust the instant into the same time zone for comparison of dates.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Interrogate for the date-only value, a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ldt = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

Lastly, compare the `LocalDate` objects.

```
Boolean givenMomentIsAfterToday = ldt.isAfter( today );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.